# Mysql query In QUERY with only 1 result for each in id

Tags: php, mysql

Please excuse the vagueness of my title, I really don't know how to succinctly write what I am trying to do.

I have a table with

name - str
item_id - int
position - int

```
  name        item_id   position
| 6asd |          17 |        1 |
| asdf |           3 |        1 |
| asdf |           3 |        2 |
| asdf |           3 |        3 |
| asdf |           3 |        4 |
```

I am trying to use an IN query on a list of `item_ids` and only return 1 row per item and that should be the row with the lowest position.

```
select name, item_id, position from my_table 
WHERE item_id IN (17, 3) AND name != '';
```

This returns all rows for the item_id when I am only trying to return the lowest position.  Naturally I looked at ORDER_BY and LIMIT but my query only is done on the whole results set not on each id individually.

`ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1`

Has anyone tried to do this before?? any help would be greatly appreciated. Do I need to use a subselect somehow?

Comment: @Bono i think that's exactly what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[MIN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min)** that is available.

```
SELECT name, item_id, MIN(position)
FROM my_table 
WHERE item_id IN (17, 3) AND name != ''
GROUP BY item_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the [MIN()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-min-function.htm) function.

> MySQL MIN function is used to find out the record with minimum value among a record set.

Try something along these lines:

```
"SELECT name, item_id, MIN(position) 
 FROM my_table 
 WHERE item_id IN (17, 3) AND name != ''
 GROUP BY item_id";
```

Comment: @FahimParkar Thanks, not a real sql guru here ;P